# How to ascertain dpi of image inside a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, resolution, adobe-acrobat

The Income Tax Department of my country wants me to upload certain financial documents to their website. They say only PDF files are allowed and documents (Paper based records) to be scanned to PDF with 300 dpi resolution.

I have a scanner that can scan and convert document to PDF at 300 dpi. However once I have a PDF file, how do I ascertain that it indeed is a result of 300 dpi scan?

There’s some related article on the Internet that expects Acrobat Pro. What I have is only the Acrobat Reader.  Thanks.

Comment: Since scanned documents are images you can use an image editor to find out resolution.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF format, like its predecessor PostScript, is meant to be a resolution-independent document format, but it can contain embedded images which themselves contain a resolution specification.

The `pdfimages` command from the [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) software package can display this information. On macOS, you can install this using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) in the Terminal:

```
brew install poppler
```

The run the command like this:

```
pdfimages -list /path/to/yourfile.pdf
```

The output looks like:

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1710   758  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         8  0   200   200 44.3K 1.2%
   2     1 image    1667  2139  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        22  0   200   200  560K 5.4%
```

The `x-ppi` and `y-ppi` values show the resolution for the image on that page.